# React Native Grid View : Image messes up the view

Tags: ios, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

I'm building an app that requires a Grid View. So far my grid works fine as you can see on the image below, the red squares are well positioned. Though, when I add an image in each box, it messes up the grid (second picture). Any ideas why ?

This is the screenshots (first image works fine with margins and is centered)

[image: view works fine with margins and is centered]

Second image has no more margins in the middle and on the right side

[image: no more margins in the middle and on the right side]

And this is the code that generates the view :

```
    renderData = (data) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.box}>
                <Text style={styles.boxText}>{data.name}</Text>

                // This is what I add to display the image
                <Image 
                 source={data.image} 
                 style={styles.boxImage} />
            </View>
        );
    }

    renderPage() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.filterButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.filterButtonMessage}>
                        Occasions
                    </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
                    dataSource={this.state.data2}
                    renderRow={this.renderData} />
            </View>
        );
    }
    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
         container: {
             flex: 1,
        },
        list: {
             flex: 1,
             flexDirection: 'row',
             flexWrap: 'wrap',
             justifyContent: 'center'
        },
        box: {
            width: 150,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            height: 150,
            alignItems: 'stretch',
            margin: 3
        },
        boxImage: {
            flex: 1
        },
        boxText: {
            flex: 1,
            fontWeight: '900',
            fontSize: 15,
            color: 'white',
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 5,
            right: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried...

```
boxImage: { 
    flex: 1, 
    width: 150, 
    height: 150,
},
```

Comment: Thanks, works well ! Why si the image not taking the view's space though and takes more ?